# Permutations of int arrays that sum to 16

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, loops, max

I have a method that will return a double based on the value. Each int in the array will be between 1 through 6, signifying consecutive dice rolls.

The array could be 16 slots large or as small as 4, and the order matters. I am at a loss as to how I can code in java to look at every permutation that totals to at least 16. Looking online yielded no aid.

My pitiful code for this is below

```
public double findMax() {
    int[] dice = new int[gameBoard.length];
    for(int x : dice) x = 1;
    double max = playGame(dice);
    /* 
    int pos = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
        double test = playGame(dice);
        if(test > max) test = max;
    */

    //This is where I need help, to use the int[] dice for all combinations
    //playGame(dice) yields a double
}
```

Comment: So in essence you want all the combinations of that array which can give total of 16?

Comment: order sensitive yes, and the array size is not fixed, making the situation way more confusing for me

Comment: But as you have mentioned that it is about a die..how can array how more than 6 elements?

Comment: Perhaps I can be more clear.  each index is a dice roll, the result is an int stored in dice.  So, in order to reach 16, I will roll a maximum of 16 dice, each index having an int of 1

Comment: Got it..will provide you the code in some time..

Comment: What (range of values) does `playGame` return? If it's 1-6 (`int`), why does it return a `double`.

Comment: any double from 0 to the max value of a double

Comment: So that's a random generator? And you can't use any [standard Java random function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int))? Otherwise, what's the point of the function?

Comment: Sounds like perhaps you want us to do your homework assignment for you?

Comment: nay.  The playGame() uses an ArrayList of doubles that correspond to spaces on a board and their costs.  Once you get to the end of the board, you are done(16 spaces long).  Basically it is dependent on the values of the doubles inside that ArrayList what the theoretical max value is.  But it doesnt change that for any set on that Arraylist, some int[] of dicerolls will yield the largest double

Comment: Kevin, I actually dont.  I have done plenty of research and time into this but, aside from homework, I do not understand how to find the combinations of an array.  I spent the last few hours actually writing the game, but this last method, to find what the theoretical maximum is for my given boardstate, is difficult.

Comment: You lost me. I read this as "I want to generate all possible dice rolls (values 1-6) that can add up to 16" (so it can be 6+6+4 or 6+5+5 or 6+3+3+4 or whatever), but this clearly doesn't seem to be it. Can you provide some example data? (Side note - you should easily be able to find code for permutation generation in Java, if that's what this is asking)

Comment: To redefine, again.  4,3,4, 1, 4 is a valid set of rolls.  as would be 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1 , 1, 1, 6.    The extra of the last roll is ignored, and the value is finished.  The question is how to permute when the size of the array keeps changing and still keep the array order specific.

Comment: @Grog_MalBlood there is an array of 4 to 16 elements, each element is from 1 to 6. and your question is how many way you can add up to 16 using all/some elements in this array? Is this correct? why the content of the array keep changing? Does that mean you can only use one element once?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this, but recursion seems to be the best to me (like pathfinding algorithms). It appears that this is supposed to be for permutations of 4 to 16 dice roll that total 16 or greater (If the array has a length of 16, every combination possible will yield a value of 16 or greater, so I'm not sure what purpose checking the permutations of that length would yield).

I can implement the solution using ArrayLists or using Strings. I don't want to use regular arrays in the recursive functions since they rely on a fixed size. Just be sure to add `import java.util.ArrayList;` though.

Anyways, here is my version of the code using ArrayLists. (Note, I haven't tested this code yet)

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<int>> findPermutations( int size ) {

    // To allow the function to work with sizes less than 1
    if ( size < 1 )
        return new ArrayList<ArrayList<int>>();

    ArrayList<ArrayList<int>> permutations = new ArrayList<ArrayList<int>>();

    ArrayList<ArrayList<int>> l1 = findPermutations( new ArrayList<int>(), size, 1 );
    l1.addAll( findPermutations( new ArrayList<int>(), size, 2 ) );
    l1.addAll( findPermutations( new ArrayList<int>(), size, 3 ) );
    l1.addAll( findPermutations( new ArrayList<int>(), size, 4 ) );
    l1.addAll( findPermutations( new ArrayList<int>(), size, 5 ) );
    l1.addAll( findPermutations( new ArrayList<int>(), size, 6 ) );


    for( ArrayList<int> a : l1 ) {
        if ( computeSum( a ) >= 16 ) {
            permutations.add( a );
        }
    }

    return permutations;

}

public ArrayList<ArrayList<int>> findPermutations( ArrayList<int> record, int size, int value ) {


    record.add( value );

    if ( record.size() >= size ) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<int>> bc = new ArrayList<ArrayList<int>>();
        bc.add( record );
        return bc;
    }

    ArrayList<ArrayList<int>> permutations = findPermutations( record.clone(), size, 1 );
    permutations.addAll( findPermutations( record.clone(), size, 2 ) );
    permutations.addAll( findPermutations( record.clone(), size, 3 ) );
    permutations.addAll( findPermutations( record.clone(), size, 4 ) );
    permutations.addAll( findPermutations( record.clone(), size, 5 ) );
    permutations.addAll( findPermutations( record.clone(), size, 6 ) );

    // For variable size array checking
    if ( record.size() >= 4 ) {
        permutations.add( record );
    }


    return permutations;
}


public int computeSum( ArrayList<int> list ) {

    int total = 0;
    for( int x : list ) {
        total += x;
    }

    return total;

}
```

And when you call this function `findPermutations( int size )`, you pass in the size (the array length, essentially the game board length) and it will generate all dice roll combinations (order specific) that have a total of at least 16. Since this returns an ArrayList, if you want to turn that into a double array, you can use the `toArray()` function of the ArrayList class.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<int>> permutations = findPermutations( 16 );
ArrayList<int>[] a = ( ArrayList<int>[] ) permutations.toArray();
```

This will give you an array of ArrayList

To convert it into an array of arrays, a loop can be used.

```
int[][] finalVersion = new int[permutations.size()][16];
for( int i = 0; i < permutations.size(); i++ ) {
    finalVersion[i] = ( int[] ) a[i].toArray();
}
```

That should hopefully convert it back into an array of arrays.

Again, I haven't tested this yet in code, so be wary of bugs. I will test this now, and add another method of doing this calculation without using ArrayLists later.

Edit: I changed the code a little bit so as to allow all permutations ***between*** 4 and size (which you can just pass in 16).

Comment: Note: the recursive calls could be changed to for loops to make the code smaller and to allow for variable dice sizes (Like a dodecahedron, a 12 sided dice). I just did it that way because I was being lazy.

Comment: @Grog_MalBlood Since I don't have enough rep to comment on your question, I'll ask you here. Do you want the function to list all permutations between size 4 and 16, or just for a fixed size in that range? I ask because the code I have listed now only add permutations of a fixed size, but it can easily be changed for a variable size with two lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple. Initialize a big enough array. Recursively, fill the elements of the array, until you hit 16 (store the array) or overshoot (discard). Don't forget to make a deep copy of the array every time you add it to the results list, otherwise you will keep on overwriting the same array. In code:

```
void createPermutations(int[] prefix, int index, int sum, List<Integer[]> results) {
    if (sum == 16) {
        results.add(createNewIntegerArray(prefix, index));
    } else if (sum < 16) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
            prefix[index] = i;
            createPermutations(prefix, index+1, sum+i, results);            
        }
    }
}

Integer[] createNewIntegerArray(int[] array, int length) {
    Integer[] result = new Integer[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result[i] = array[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

You would call this as:

```
createPermutations(new int[16], 0, 0, new ArrayList<Integer[]>());
```

---

EDIT: if I misinterpreted your question and you don't care about 'overshooting' the target value (16), you should change `==` to `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it recursively:

```
Input: list of size n

Solve(n) = { Sum(n,16) } + Solve(n-1)

with: Solve(4) = { Sum(4,16) }

Sum(n,16) = { find n numbers that sum up to 16 }
```

Then we have:

```
Min(n) = 4

Max(n) = 16

Di = Input-List[i]

Di = 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6

Sum(n,16) = { D1, D2, .. Dn } where D1 + D2 + .. + Dn = 16
```

---

To solve `Sum(n,16)` you can try this algorithm (written as **Java** code):

```
PairList<ArrayList<Byte>,Integer> sum (int n, int sum, ArrayList<Byte> list)
{
    if (list.size() == 1)
        return new Pair<ArrayList<Byte>,Integer>(list, (int)list.get(0));

    PairList<ArrayList<Byte>,Integer> result
                  = new Pair<ArrayList<Byte>,Integer> ();

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        ArrayList<Byte> t = new ArrayList<Byte>(list);
        t.remove(i);
        PairList<ArrayList<Byte>,Integer> r = sum(n-1, sum, t);

        for (ArrayList<Byte> l : r.getFirstList())
            if (r.getSecond(l)+list.get(i) <= sum)
            {
                l.append(list.get(i));
                r.set(l, r.getSecond(l)+list.get(i));
                result.append(r);
            }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then `Solve(n,16)` using `Sum(n,16)`:

```
Map<Byte, PairList<ArrayList<Byte>,Integer>>
            solve (int min_n, int max_n, int sum, ArrayList<Byte> list)
{
    Map<Byte, PairList<ArrayList<Byte>,Integer>> solution = null;
    solution = new Map<Byte, Pair<ArrayList<Byte>,Integer>> ();

    for (int i = min_n, i <= max_n; i++)
        solution.put(i, sum(i,sum,list));

   for (int i = min_n, i <= max_n; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < solution.get(i).count(); j++)
       {
           // remove all pairs that didn't sum up to total sum

           if (solution.get(i).getSecond(j) != sum)
               solution.get(i).removePair(j);
       }
   }

    return solution;
}
```

*Note: the above code is a pseudo-code*